# What is cinderblock?

Tags: cinderblock, concrete-block

I live in the UK and have never heard of cinderblock, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderblock - easy way to describe this one. They're just concrete blocks that stack together (much like legos). They're held together with mortar like bricks. They're very common for foundation work in the US.

Comment: In the UK they are just called concrete blocks

Comment: ahh gotcha, difference in terminology (elevator vs. lift) :)

Comment: Cinder blocks are actually made from a lower-grade material than concrete blocks (see the article referenced in the answer).   The ones I am familiar with are lighter in weight, and have a more irregular appearance than concrete blocks, due to the cinders embedded in them.

Answer (score 2):

Another term for these is breeze block in the UK or besser block in Australia.

As the are larger than bricks a wall can be built more quickly than with bricks. They are usually used for the interior skin of a cavity wall and any interior load bearing walls.